# xCode iOS override hardware button functions

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode5

I'm new to stackoverflow. I'm an IT Operative in an Apple DC.
For the process I made a functional testing app for iPhones and iPads.

Last week we started a new project with some specialised repairings with another company at other side of the road.
After when we received the devices back from the other company after the specific repair, we test this specific repair which has to do with the hardware buttons, with an app.
Inside this app they disabled the functions of all 5 hardware buttons (volume up/volumedown, mute, home and power).

But because it's made by Apple Diagnostics Team, they won't share this part with me.
However I wrote an workaround for this, the app will be send to the background when pressed the home or lock button.

The devices are not jailbroken. The disabling only works in a the specific button test viewcontroller.

My question is, how can I do this in my app aswell? Because it will save up like .. 10 - 15 seconds per device.

It should be possible with GSEvent or a springboard hook, does anyone have any experience with this ?
I hope to find some help over here, everywhere I ask this I get:
No it's not possible, no why would you do that, no it will be blocked by the App Store, no you need jailbroken device for it.

Oh did I mention it's only for inhouse distribution and stays inhouse?

Comment: For the Home button, is it possible to ask the system to open a URL which the app itself responds to, causing it to reopen? Or, on home button press, use a URL to launch another app, which in turn relaunches your app? It wouldn’t help with the sleep/wake button, but maybe for the Home button.

Comment: @Zev Eisenberg, I don't know how to override the function of the Home Button. Do you have/know any documentation or related post about this? For the volume buttons I override the functions, however it doesn't work for the mute button as its linking to the ringer instead of normal volume.

Comment: Detect when your app goes to the background by using `-applicationWillResignActive:`. I don’t know if you can launch another app from there using `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:@"someotherapp://somequery"]`, but it’s worth a try. Of course, if you can successfully, leave the app, it means the Home button is working.

Comment: Right now I am detecting the app going to background and with comparing screenbrightness I can detect difference between home and lock. As the lock button will turn brightness off :) but it would be better to override these functions. Or at least relaunch the app itself once going background. (For the home button) I will give it a try later when my wife's birthday is over ;)

Comment: I have seen a few posts about this with an possible solution by installing an home block mobileconfig. Is it possible to still detect the button? And if so. Can I activate and deactivate this in my app? As I only want to block it in my button test view.